# Text file writing: next line starting from last value

Tags: python, matlab, networkx, pytorch-geometric

I have a list of networkx graphs, and I am trying to write a text file containing a massive edge list of all graphs. If you run the following code:

```
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset

dataset = TUDataset(root='data/TUDataset', name='MUTAG')
```

Then do to data->TUDataset->MUTAG->raw, I am trying to replicate the raw files but using my data.

My raw data is a MATLAB .mat file containing a struct where the first column `A` is each individual graph's corresponding adjacency matrix where i create the networkx graph:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd
raw_data = loadmat('data_final3.mat', squeeze_me=True)
data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data['Graphs'])

import networkx as nx
A = data.pop('A')
nx_graph = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    nx_graph.append(nx.Graph(A[i]))
```

I created the MUTAG_graph_indicator file using:

```
with open('graph_indicator.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(nx_graph)):
        f.write((str(i)+'\n')*len(nx_graph[i].nodes))
```

If there is a way to do this either using python or MATLAB, I would greatly appreciate the help. Yes, torch_geometric does have from_networkx, but it doesn't seem to contain the same information as if I created the torch_geometric graphs the same way as the sample data.